# How to check if collectionview is empty xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, view, collections

I have a collection view. I want to make this :

If there is no images added to the collection view, I want an imageview to be visible. But if there is 1 or more images added to the collection, I want the imageview to become invisible

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to call this method in viewDidLoad, as well as anywhere the collection view could have it's contents modified.  If assumes you have IBOutlets connected to your UICollectionView and your UIImageView:

```
- (void) showAppropriateView
{
    int numberOfItemsInCollection = [collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
    if( numberOfItemsInCollection > 0 )
    {
        collectionView.hidden = NO;
        imageView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        collectionView.hidden = YES;
        imageView.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

I'm not at a Mac right now, so I can't be certain this will work, but I don't see any reason is wouldn't.

Comment: Is there something like this we can do ?
If collectionviewitems > 0
imageView.hidden = YES;
else imageView.hidden =NO;

I dont know good programming but i thought of this I dont know if i'm right

Comment: That is what the code is doing.  I tested it our locally and it is correctly hiding the view when the collection view is empty.  When I have items loaded in the collection view, it is visible.    If your imageView is always visible, you either have not correctly connected it to the IBOutlet, or your colection view thinks it has no cells in section 0.  Put a breakpoint at the first line of that method and see what values you are getting, as well as checking if the imageView is not null.

Comment: I did everything right, connected the outlets. XCode gave a warning that i need to use '_collectionView' instead of 'collectionView' so i changed that. But the code doesn't work for me

Comment: Is there a opportunity that we can do this with an if statement ?

Comment: I did, but logically it is the exact same as my initial code.  I've edited it to put it in an if statement.  I did test it locally and it is working for me.  The logic is not the problem, something else is not hooked up right.

Comment: If there is no item in the collectionview, it makes the colletionview invisible but doesn't make the imageview visible :S

Comment: Ok. I fixed it. When the collectionview is hidden. Also imageview doesnt show up so deleting this line solves the problem:collectionView.hidden = YES;

Comment: The problem isn't with the code.  I think the problem is that your imageView referencing outlet is not connected. I'm glad you got it working, but there is some other problem.  The code above correctly toggles the showing and hiding of two components.  Removing that line of code should not make it work.  The code in the post above, with correctly connected outlets, does exactly what you are asking.

Comment: When there is no item in the collection view. collection view is not visible so I think there is no need to hide it

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming collectionViewArray is the name of your array you are loading into the collection view. Change collectionViewArray to the name of your array. This is also assuming your UIImageView is called imageView. Replace imageView with whatever your UIImageView is called.

```
-(void)testCollectionView {
    BOOL visible;
    if (collectionViewArray.count == 0) { 
         imageView.hidden = NO;
    } else if (collectionViewArray.count >= 1) {
         imageView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if collectionViewArray is not nill

```
if (self.collectionViewArray != nil) {
  // your code here
}
```